# Error testing webclient.get() method result: "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$RequestHeadersUriSpec.uri(String, Object[])"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, webclient

Receipt error testing webclient.get() method result: "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$RequestHeadersUriSpec.uri(String, Object[])"

this is it my error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$RequestHeadersSpec.retrieve()" because the return value of "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$RequestHeadersUriSpec.uri(String, Object[])" is null
```

Why doesn't it work?

What am I doing wrong to receive null data in the uri ?

My code testing is :

TEST.java :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
class FaroApiRestTest {

    @Mock
    private WebClient.Builder builder;
    @Mock
    private WebClient webClient;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec rhus;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec rhs;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.ResponseSpec rs;
    @Mock
    private FaroApiConfig apiConfig;

    private FaroApiRest faroApiRest;
    private static final String URL_FARO = "http://localhost:8080/faro.dev";
    private static final String URL_FARO_GETCITIES= "/getCities/{codeProvince}";


@BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        apiConfig = Mockito.spy(new FaroApiConfig(URL_FARO));
        faroApiRest = new FaroApiRest(apiConfig);

        //Initialize webClient Builder Mock
        when(builder.baseUrl(URL_FARO)).thenReturn(builder);
        when(builder.defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)).thenReturn(builder);
        when(builder.build()).thenReturn(webClient);
        when(apiConfig.webClient()).thenReturn(webClient);

    }

@Test
    void getCities(){
        List<Object> cities = new ArrayList<>();
        cities.add("Jersey");
        String codeProvince = "856";

        when(webClient.get()).thenReturn(rhus);
        when(rhus.uri(URL_FARO_GETCITIES, codeProvince)).thenReturn(rhs);
        when(rhus.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).thenReturn(rhs);
        when(rhs.retrieve()).thenReturn(rs);
        when(rs.bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Object>>() {})).thenReturn(Mono.just(cities));

        //given
        List<Object> response = faroApiRest.getCities(codeProvince);

        //then
        assertNotNull(response);
        verify(rhs).retrieve();
        verify(webClient).get();
    }
```

Comment: Resolved -> not reconized uri, solution : uri("/getCities/856").thenReturn(rhs)